# PM3d and Impulses combined not scaling

Tags: gnuplot, autoscaling

I am new to gnuplot, but I think I have all the basics.  I am trying to plot a 3d surface with some impulses.  When I do each splot individually, they look great, but when I splot them together, the scale gets all messed up.  Any thoughts?  Autoscale is set in all cases.

1st splot:

```
splot "C:/data/file1.dat" matrix rowheaders columnheaders with pm3d
```

[image: matrix]

2nd splot:

```
splot "C:/Data/file2.dat" with impulses, "C:/Data/file2.dat" with points pt 7
```

[image: Impulses]

Combined:

```
splot "C:/data/file1.dat" matrix rowheaders columnheaders with pm3d, \                                                                            
    "C:/Data/file2.dat" with impulses, \
    "C:/Data/file2.dat" with points pt 7
```

[image: Combined]

See how the scale gets all messed up, and the first chart gets scrunched down to one corner?  Both data sets have roughly the same ranges in data.

file1.dat

```
    6   8   10  12  16  20  24
30  3.513999939 4.515999794 5.293000221 5.894999981 6.633999825 6.870999813 6.901000023
35  4.235000134 5.330999851 6.169000149 6.72300005  7.196000099 7.374000072 7.434000015
40  4.818999767 5.940999985 6.776000023 7.171000004 7.558000088 7.722000122 7.802999973
45  5.291999817 6.453999996 7.136000156 7.480999947 7.831999779 7.997000217 8.092000008
50  5.656000137 6.791999817 7.393000126 7.718999863 8.057999611 8.232999802 8.340000153
55  5.968999863 7.014999866 7.587999821 7.913000107 8.255000114 8.44299984  8.565999985
60  6.225999832 7.176000118 7.741000175 8.079999924 8.434000015 8.642000198 8.788000107
65  6.414000034 7.326000214 7.859000206 8.225999832 8.602000237 8.840000153 9.015000343
70  6.624000072 7.494999886 7.956999779 8.357000351 8.767000198 9.039999962 9.25
75  6.801000118 7.638999939 8.100999832 8.468000412 8.930000305 9.251999855 9.496999741
80  6.93599987  7.758999825 8.222000122 8.56799984  9.107999802 9.491000175 9.772000313
85  7.035999775 7.855000019 8.322999954 8.690999985 9.289999962 9.748999596 10.10700035
90  7.102000237 7.919000149 8.409999847 8.80300045  9.470999718 10.03199959 10.47500038
95  7.125   7.933000088 8.479000092 8.901000023 9.642999649 10.31599998 10.83600044
100 7.107999802 7.907999992 8.534000397 8.987000465 9.812000275 10.60000038 11.18799973
105 7.053999901 7.849999905 8.515999794 9.06000042  9.972999573 10.86600018 11.52400017
110 6.965000153 7.769999981 8.43500042  9.090999603 10.11800003 11.10400009 11.84200001
115 6.840000153 7.663000107 8.309000015 8.961000443 10.24100018 11.31099987 12.14299965
120 6.672999859 7.524000168 8.149999619 8.75399971  10.32299995 11.48900032 12.42500019
125 6.436999798 7.349999905 7.961999893 8.529000282 9.987000465 11.64599991 12.68999958
130 6.044000149 7.133999825 7.749000072 8.298000336 9.579000473 11.67500019 12.96199989
135 5.572000027 6.856999874 7.513000011 8.06499958  9.237999916 11.11900043 13.27099991
140 5.127999783 6.440000057 7.257999897 7.831999779 8.937999725 10.52499962 12.90999985
145 4.683000088 5.933000088 6.981999874 7.598999977 8.670000076 10.0170002  12.10299969
150 4.30700016  5.52699995  6.657999992 7.363999844 8.425999641 9.602999687 11.39599991
155 3.996999979 5.196000099 6.294000149 7.122000217 8.194000244 9.262000084 10.79100037
160 3.730999947 4.887000084 5.936999798 6.868999958 7.973999977 8.970999718 10.27600002
165 3.506999969 4.620999813 5.642000198 6.610000134 7.78000021  8.737999916 9.892000198
170 3.342999935 4.421999931 5.427999973 6.385000229 7.625   8.56499958  9.626999855
175 3.233999968 4.288000107 5.281000137 6.217000008 7.506999969 8.43900013  9.44299984
180 3.170000076 4.209000111 5.191999912 6.111000061 7.428999901 8.354000092 9.32199955
```

file2.dat

```
7.5 172.0   4.5
5.6 56.8    4.7
6.7 35.0    5.1
11.0    158.7   5.3
13.8    24.8    5.6
12.1    180.0   6.0
5.1 83.2    6.4
13.2    158.0   6.6
15.8    34.5    6.67
15.6    32.9    6.69
11.8    180.0   6.8
13.7    96.0    7.2
15.0    62.4    7.3
11.2    76.2    7.3
11.7    84.9    7.4
13.8    121.8   7.46
9.7 90.9    7.6
13.2    66.0    7.64
14.3    61.3    7.8
14.8    124.6   8.0
9.5 118.8   8.20
15.1    148.8   8.29
12.2    81.8    8.4
```

Comment: Please post a complete, minimal working example. There is something very strange going on with your axes.... in your first plot, there are seemingly equidistant grid lines at 8, 10, 12, 16, 20, 24?!?

Comment: I posted the files' data.  I am not sure what is wrong with "equidistant grid lines."  It looks like what I would have expected.  Should they not be equidistant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in your first image that the spacing between x=10 and x=12 is as big as the spacing between x=12 and x=16, which gives a clue to what's going on: while first plot looks like gnuplot is using the x coordinates 8,10,12,16,20,24, those are really only labels, while numerically gnuplot uses the x coordinates 0,1,2,3,4,5,6. So when you then plot the second graph on the same scale, the data points have x values between 5.1 and 15.8, so will show up the side of the pm3d surface.

If you want gnuplot to use the first column and first row as actual coordinates, you have to use the nonuniform matrix format (see `help matrix nonuniform`). First, you need to change your data file `file1.dat` to start with the number 7, the number of columns. The beginning of the file should look like this:

```
7   6   8   10  12  16  20  24
30  3.513999939 4.515999794 5.293000221 5.894999981 6.633999825 6.870999813 6.901000023
35  4.235000134 5.330999851 6.169000149 6.72300005  7.196000099 7.374000072 7.434000015
```

Then you can plot the data as follows:

```
splot "file1.dat" nonuniform matrix w pm3d, \
      "file2.dat" with impulses, \
      "file2.dat" with points pt 7
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent.  There is still a lot to learn!  While I have you, do you know if there is a way to make the matrix plot opaque, so we can see which lollipops are above and which below as we spin it?

Comment: For that we you have to `set hidden3d`. However, that doesn't work with `pm3d`, so you have to draw the surface `with lines` instead.